# Package "fontconfig" not found

Tags: void-linux

When trying to compile [Luke Smith's fork of st](http://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st) on voidlinux, I get the error

```
Package fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing "fontconfig..pc"
```

When using the `find` command, I don't find the .pc file anywhere, however running `xbps-install` shows it's already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late reply but try installing the base-devel package from the void linux repository.

```
xbps-install base-devel
```

Everything should compile afterwards.